# How to stop Json.NET JArray.Parse from changing utc dates?

Tags: .net, json.net

If I have a JSON string with a property which looks like a UTC date, example: "**2017-08-25T16:49:27.777-07:00**", Json.NET's JArray.Parse modifies the date to another time zone. Is there a way to disable this? I want the date to stay as is. 
I tried placing this before the parse

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
};
```

and it had no effect. The JsonLoadSettings class doesn't have a property for handling dates.

Update
This is happening after I change the timezone in my computer. -7 is PDT. I was trying to test my date conversion using different time zones. The date after changing my computer timezone from Pacific to Eastern, after JArray.Parse it becomes "2017-08-25T19:49:27.753-04:00". This messes up my own date conversion where I am trying to convert from supposedly always utc to local machine time.

Comment: It didn't do anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested two different approaches, one using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject<T>` and the other one using `JArray.Load(JsonReader)`. Both approaches work for me, regardless of my local time zone.

```
var serialized = "[\"2017-08-25T20:57:14.3914448+02:00\",\"2017-08-25T18:57:14.3914448+00:00\"]";

//Using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
var resultA = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset>>(serialized);

//Using JArray /w JsonReader
var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(serialized)){DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset};
var resultB = JArray.Load(jsonReader);
```

However, I don't understand why you state:

> This messes up my own date conversion where I am trying to convert from supposedly always utc to local machine time.

It's obviously not UTC time, so it should not be treated as such. UTC is basically Greenwich time (time zone offset 0), but your date time string is reprensenting a time zone offset of -7 hours.

Comment: I would like to stick with using JArray.Parse otherwise I have to change a lot of code. It's UTC datetime without the offset. I would like JArray.Parse to ignore the offset.

Comment: You cannot do that using JArray.Parse (see https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/862). Also, are you saying that the time zone portion of the date string is wrong? If so, do you have control over how it is generated so it could be changed to Z or +00:00 to properly represent UTC?

Comment: Everything works now using JArray.Load. I am ignoring the offset in the datetime.